# Draggable TextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

Is there any way to create a draggable textbox in WPF ? I can see lot of ways of creating draggable TextBlock in WPF. But can't find a similar way to achieve this for Textbox.

Comment: Could you explain what you would like to happen when there is a text in the text box and the user clicks and drags the text; should the box move or should the text be (partially) selected?

Comment: When the user clicks on it, should be able to edit the text and when he starts dragging it should move

Comment: @Lajesh Did you succeed? Could you tell how you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a drag is started if the mouse is moved a few pixels while at least one mouse button is down. This "pattern" also appears when selecting text in a textbox. It seems there will be no way to tell this actions apart, so this might be the reason there is no "movable textbox" designed this way.

As a possible way to solve your problem you could take this approach into account: [Universally usable editable label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368931/universally-usable-editable-label/32369800#32369800)

Alternatively you could add some area to your textbox, which reacts to moving.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Rectangle x:Name="DraggablePart" .../>
  <TextBox .../>
</StackPanel>
```

Or even some kind of adorner, which will appear only, when the textbox is hovered.